# Can't locate element on google chrome webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to change the chrome profile name on this like : `chrome://settings/manageProfile` using Python and Selenium :

It's the empty textbox on the top left corner:
[image]

The issue is that I can't access to the element, I tried all the stuff below :

```
chromeProfilName = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='profile-name']")

chromeProfilName = browser.find_element(By.ID, "profile-name")

chromeProfilName = browser.find_element(By.ID, "input")
```

I don't really understand how the HTML page is made, but when I examine the page, I found the `textboxID = "input"`. However, the value is stored in a span, which ID is `"profile-name".`

I always have the same issue : "no such element: Unable to locate element". I don't have a deep knowledge about Selenium. I already looked for answers on internet but I found nothing.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the **input** element you need traverse through `shadowroot` element.Use the following `querySelector` to indentify the **input** tag.

```
driver.get("chrome://settings/manageProfile")
profileInput = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("settings-ui").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-main").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-basic-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-people-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-manage-profile").shadowRoot.querySelector("cr-input").shadowRoot.querySelector("#input")')
profileInput.click()
profileInput.clear()
profileInput.send_keys("user676767")
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks ! Is it possible to explain (quickly) why it's impossible to access it with XPATH, CSS, ID, ... ?

Comment: If you see the DOM structure the element present under shadowRoot element.You need to traverse through that element.Yes you can use css selector however queryselector is the easiest way to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, I just want to add something :

For those who thought you've to search yourself the path with shadowroots, in reality you don't have to.

With Chrome for exemple (it's not possible on Firefox), when you target the element in the source code, copy the "JS path". Then you just have to paste the path in the execute_script function.